# Using conditional statement for attribute data with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, arcgis-pro

I'm working on a code, I want to be able to update(change) a value in the attributes table using a python code and I've used the update cursor function but the code isn't working, nothing changes.

I will show you my code and tell me if anything is wrong with it:

```
fc = "SmartMeter1"  field = ['OBJECTID','ON']  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field) as cursor:  
 for row in cursor:
    if row[0]==2:
        row[1]=0
    else:
        print ('no fault')
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

this is the code, as you can see i'm trying to use the update cursor to change the attribute value to 0 if the objectiid equals 2 and this is my attribute table:

[image]

so I want to change the second row to 0, this is just initially and if this works I will further expand my code.

Can you can tell me how I can fix my code and make it work, or if there is another function other than update cursor i can use?

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as a screenshot

Comment: In addition to BERA's answer, is `'ON'` is a type of string or integer. If it is string, it should be `str(0)` so that else statement can accept `row[1] ='no fault'`, but if the type is integer `row[1] = 0` will work but `row[1] ='no fault'` will not work because you are adding a string into an integer type.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if row[0]=='2'` to `if row[0]==2`. You are checking for the string '2' when you should be checking for the integer 2